# youtube dash ingest validation issue

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to push a dash stream to youtube instead of using rtmp. I used the API's to create a stream with ingestion type dash and binded it to a live broadcast.

Then I used FFmpeg to create a live dash stream and tried to PUT it to the dash_upload API but I always get a 400 back with the message "Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. MPD is unparseable. That’s all we know.." I even tried a few other mpd files I found online (all passed the MPEG-DASH MPD Validator).

Is there a way to see more detailed logs or anything showing what is wrong or does anyone have some example mpd's that work?

Here is basically what I tried:

PUT
https://upload.youtube.com/dash_upload?cid=jsjb-sb9q-4wqj-XXXX&copy=0&file=dash.mpd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd"
    profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011"
    type="dynamic"
    minimumUpdatePeriod="PT6S"
    suggestedPresentationDelay="PT6S"
    availabilityStartTime="2018-10-10T20:02:08Z"
    publishTime="2018-10-10T20:02:33Z"
    minBufferTime="PT12.7S">
    <ProgramInformation>
    </ProgramInformation>
    <Period id="0" start="PT0.0S">
        <AdaptationSet id="0" contentType="video" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true">
            <Representation id="0" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42c028" bandwidth="3002151" width="1920" height="1080" frameRate="10000000/333333">
                <SegmentTemplate timescale="10000000" initialization="init-stream$RepresentationID$.m4s" media="chunk-stream$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.m4s" startNumber="1">
                    <SegmentTimeline>
                        <S t="0" d="63999936" r="3" />
                    </SegmentTimeline>
                </SegmentTemplate>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet id="1" contentType="audio" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true">
            <Representation id="1" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="130979" audioSamplingRate="44100">
                <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2" />
                <SegmentTemplate timescale="44100" initialization="init-stream$RepresentationID$.m4s" media="chunk-stream$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.m4s" startNumber="1">
                    <SegmentTimeline>
                        <S t="0" d="283153" />
                        <S d="281556" />
                        <S d="282668" />
                        <S d="281600" />
                    </SegmentTimeline>
                </SegmentTemplate>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>
```